# Drag with Inertia D3js (v4)

Tags: javascript, d3.js, drag, smooth-scrolling

I have been struggling with the implementation of a smooth drag feature in my work. I manage to find one example as shown in this link. [Inertia Drag](https://bl.ocks.org/pjanik/5872514)
however when I try to implement `drag().inertia(true)` I got an error indicating d3 doesn't contains that function. How can I implement this? Below is my code.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    var wholeDemography = [
        { categorie: "2.33 KM", values: [{ value: 0, rate: "Speed" }, { value: 4, rate: "Occupancy" }, { value: 12, rate: "Volume" }] },
        { categorie: "4.66 KM", values: [{ value: 1, rate: "Speed" }, { value: 21, rate: "Occupancy" }, { value: 13, rate: "Volume" }] },
        { categorie: "6.99 KM", values: [{ value: 3, rate: "Speed" }, { value: 22, rate: "Occupancy" }, { value: 6, rate: "Volume" }] },
        { categorie: "9.32 KM", values: [{ value: 12, rate: "Speed" }, { value: 7, rate: "Occupancy" }, { value: 18, rate: "Volume" }] },
        { categorie: "11.65 KM", values: [{ value: 6, rate: "Speed" }, { value: 100, rate: "Occupancy" }, { value: 9, rate: "Volume" }] },
        { categorie: "13.98 KM", values: [{ value: 6, rate: "Speed" }, { value: 3, rate: "Occupancy" }, { value: 8, rate: "Volume" }] }
    ];

    var categoriesNames = wholeDemography.map(function (d) { return d.categorie; });
    var rateNames = wholeDemography[0].values.map(function (d) { return d.rate; });

    var margin = { top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 40 },
        width = 900 - margin.left - margin.right,
        height = 300 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

    var x0 = d3.scaleBand().domain(categoriesNames).rangeRound([0, width]).padding(0.5);//the padding itself is the padding between the grouped bar 

    var x1 = d3.scaleBand().domain(rateNames).rangeRound([0, x0.bandwidth()]);

    var y = d3.scaleLinear().domain([0, d3.max(wholeDemography, function (categorie) { 
        return d3.max(categorie.values, function (d) { 
            return d.value; }); })])
        .range([height, 0]);

    var xAxis = d3.axisBottom()
        .tickSize(0)
        .scale(x0);

    var yAxis = d3.axisLeft()
        .scale(y);

    var color = d3.scaleOrdinal()
        .range(["#a58ea2", "#f8512f", "#edfeeb"]);

    var svg = d3.select('.whitepaper').append("svg")
        .attr("class", "groupedbarcontext")
        .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
        .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
        .append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

    y.domain([0, d3.max(wholeDemography, function (categorie) { return d3.max(categorie.values, function (d) { return d.value; }); })]);
    var dragable = svg.append("g")
                      .attr("class", "dragable");
    dragable.append("g")
        .attr("class", "x axis")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
        .call(xAxis);

    svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "y axis")
        .style('opacity', '0')
        .call(yAxis)
        .append("text")
        .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
        .attr("y", 6)
        .attr("dy", ".71em")
        .attr("fill", "white")//if style("color", "black") is not working change to attr("fill", "black")
        .style("text-anchor", "end")
        .style('font-weight', 'bold')
        .text("Value");

    svg.select('.y').transition().duration(500).delay(1300).style('opacity', '1');

    var slice = dragable.selectAll(".slice")
        .data(wholeDemography)
        .enter().append("g")
        .attr("class", "slice")
        .attr("transform", function (d) {
            console.log("here you are: " + x0(d.categorie));
            return "translate(" + x0(d.categorie) + ",0)";
        });

    slice.selectAll("rect")
        .data(function (d) { return d.values; })
        .enter().append("rect")
        .attr("width", x1.bandwidth())
        .attr("x", function (d) { return x1(d.rate); })
        .style("fill", function (d) { return color(d.rate) })
        .attr("y", function (d) { return y(0); })
        .attr("height", function (d) { return height - y(0); })
        .on("mouseover", function (d) {
            d3.select(this).style("fill", d3.rgb(color(d.rate)).darker(2));
        })
        .on("mouseout", function (d) {
            d3.select(this).style("fill", color(d.rate));
        });

    slice.selectAll("rect")
        .transition()
        .delay(function (d) { return Math.random() * 1000; })
        .duration(1000)
        .attr("y", function (d) { return y(d.value); })
        .attr("height", function (d) { return height - y(d.value); });

    //Legend
    var legend = svg.selectAll(".legend")
        .data(wholeDemography[0].values.map(function (d) { return d.rate; }).reverse())
        .enter().append("g")
        .attr("class", "legend")
        .attr("transform", function (d, i) { return "translate(0," + i * 20 + ")"; })
        .style("opacity", "0");

    legend.append("rect")
        .attr("x", width - 18)
        .attr("width", 18)
        .attr("height", 18)
        .style("fill", function (d) { return color(d); });

    legend.append("text")
        .attr("x", width - 24)
        .attr("y", 9)
        .attr("dy", ".35em")
        .attr("fill", "white")
        .style("text-anchor", "end")
        .text(function (d) { return d; });

    legend.transition().duration(500).delay(function (d, i) { return 1300 + 100 * i; }).style("opacity", "1");
    
    //my drag function start here
    var dragcontainer = d3.drag()
                          .on("drag", function (d, i) {
                            console.log("clicked!");
                              d3.select(this).attr("transform", "translate(" + (d.x = d3.event.x) + "," + 0 + ")");
                          });
    //the parent DOM (svg of class groupedbarchartnav)
    var parentSvg = d3.select("g.dragable").datum({ x: 0, y: 0 }).call(dragcontainer);
//my drag function end here


});
```

```css
.whitepaper {
    font: 10px sans-serif;
}

.axis path,
.axis line {
    fill: none;
    stroke: #FFFFFF;
    shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.x.axis path {
    display: none;
}

.x.axis text{
  fill:white;
}

.y.axis text{
  fill:white;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<html>

<head>
    <title>GroupedBar Chart</title>
</head>

<body style="background-color:#303030; height:auto">
  <div class="whitepaper">
  </div>
  <div class="others">
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: The example you linked to is using a customized version of D3 v3.2.2. `drag.inertia()` has never been an official part of D3. There have been some change requests (e.g. [*Inertial dragging?*](https://github.com/d3/d3-drag/issues/27) but this has not yet been implemented by Mike Bostock.

Comment: @altocumulus thanks for the reply. I see. Well then, may I know how to make the inertia drag possible in d3?